# How to properly add custom logging filters in Python modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I'm running the following snippet in Python 2.7.12 under macOS Sierra but I get `KeyError`s:

```
import logging
from PIL import Image


class TaskAddingFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.Filter.__init__(self)

    def filter(self, record):
        record.args = record.args + ('task', '')


logging.basicConfig(
    filename='mylog.txt',
    format='%(asctime)-19.19s|%(task)-36s|%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(lineno)s: %(message)s',
    level=eval('logging.%s' % 'DEBUG'))

# My attempt to "monkey-patch" PIL's logger 
for name, logger in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.iteritems():
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    if name.startswith('PIL'):
        logger.addFilter(TaskAddingFilter())

logger = logging.getLogger('demo')


def tryThis():
    with open('my_image.png', 'rb') as im:
        logger.debug('Attempting to read image size...', extra={'task': '123'})
        try:
            image = Image.open(im)
            w, h = image.size
            image.save('my_image_out.png', 'PNG')
        except IOError:
            logger.error('Processing failed!', extra={'task': '123'})
            raise Exception()


tryThis()
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 861, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 734, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 469, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'task'
Logged from file PngImagePlugin.py, line 135
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried you snippet and it works fine here. just like to thank you let me learned more about `logging` module.

Comment: which line in your snippet correspond to `PngImagePlugin.py, line 135 ` ?

Comment: @CSJ It's this line: `image = Image.open(im)`. This line starts using the library along with its loggers.

Comment: you mean it already monkey patched for `PIL` before this line, right?

Comment: That's correct!

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to explicitly add the handlers you want (rather than using `basicConfig()`) and attach the filter to them. Then there's no need to patch PIL (or any other) loggers, nor to pass `extra` to logging calls. The filter method just needs to set

```
record.task = 'foo'
```

rather than messing with `record.args`.

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone else interested, I ended up opening an [issue on Pillow's repository](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2261) and thanks to contributor @wiredfool I came up with the following solution:

```
import logging
from PIL import Image


class TaskAddingFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.Filter.__init__(self)

    def filter(self, record):
        record.args = record.args + ('task', '123')


logger = logging.getLogger('THEDEMO')

Image.init()

logging.basicConfig(
    filename='mylog.txt',
    format='%(asctime)-19.19s|%(task)-36s|%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(lineno)s: %(message)s',
    level=eval('logging.%s' % 'DEBUG'))

for name, elogger in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.iteritems():
    elogger = logging.getLogger(name)
    if name.startswith('PIL'):
        elogger.addFilter(TaskAddingFilter())


def tryThis():
    with open('my_image.png', 'rb') as im:
        logger.debug('Attempting to read image size...', extra={'task': '123'})
        try:
            image = Image.open(im)
            w, h = image.size
            image.save('my_image_out.png', 'PNG')
            print 'all ran well'
        except IOError:
            logger.error('Processing failed!', extra={'task': 123})
            raise Exception()


tryThis()
```

Comment: But where does `args` come from?