# Right way to insert a variable in python logging format

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

Not able to get this one to work. Probably lack of understanding of python logging module.

Use case - print one variable on all log messages. i.e. "jobID". When multiple instances of this utility will run in parallel in same server - syslog or ../log/messages can be parsed live based on this jobID. Here is attempt with LoggerAdapter method (error lines commented) -

```
def startlog(self, log_folder, testname=None):
    if not os.path.exists(log_folder):
        os.makedirs(log_folder)

    ltime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')

    if testname:
        logfile = "%s/%s_log_%s.log" % (log_folder, testname, ltime)
    else:
        logfile = "%s/log_%s.log" % (log_folder, ltime)
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    formated = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)10s - %(funcName)10s - %(message)s')
    #What is desired is - 
    #formated = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(jobid)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)10s - %(funcName)10s - %(message)s')

    if not testname:
        fh = logging.FileHandler(filename=logfile)
        fh.setFormatter(formated)
        logger.addHandler(fh)
        ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        ch.setFormatter(formated)
        logger.addHandler(ch)
        # Next line errors -
        # logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, {"jobid": self.jobdata.jobid})
        return logger
    else:
        fh = logging.FileHandler(filename=logfile)
        fh.setFormatter(formated)
        self.log.addHandler(fh)
        # Next line errors -
        # logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(self.log, {"jobid": self.jobdata.jobid})
        return fh
```

2nd Try with Filters:

```
def startlog(self, log_folder, t_name=None):
    if not os.path.exists(log_folder):
        os.makedirs(log_folder)

    ltime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')

    if t_name:
        logfile = "%s/%s_log_%s.log" % (log_folder, t_name, ltime)
    else:
        logfile = "%s/log_%s.log" % (log_folder, ltime)
        root = logging.getLogger()
        root.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        root.addFilter(ContextFilter(self.jobdata.jobid))

    formated = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(jobid)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)10s - %(funcName)10s - %(message)s')

    if not t_name:
        fh = logging.FileHandler(filename=logfile)
        fh.setFormatter(formated)
        root.addHandler(fh)
        ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        ch.setFormatter(formated)
        root.addHandler(ch)
        return root
    else:
        fh = logging.FileHandler(filename=logfile)
        fh.setFormatter(formated)
        self.log.addHandler(fh)
        return fh


class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    """
    This is a filter which injects contextual information into the log.
    """
    def __init__(self, jobid):
        self.jobid = jobid

    def filter(self, record):
        record.jobid = self.jobid
        return True
```

Issue faced with filters is 'keyerror' from other modules(paramiko - transport.py). Similar to [How to properly add custom logging filters in Python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40846698/how-to-properly-add-custom-logging-filters-in-python-modules)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 859, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 732, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 474, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'jobid'
Logged from file transport.py, line 1567
```

Answer (score 0):

Dumb me, i need to add filter to the log handler. This is working so far -

```
    def startlog(self, log_folder, t_name=None):
    if not os.path.exists(log_folder):
        os.makedirs(log_folder)

    ltime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')

    if t_name:
        logfile = "%s/%s_log_%s.log" % (log_folder, t_name, ltime)
    else:
        logfile = "%s/log_%s.log" % (log_folder, ltime)
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    formated = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(jobid)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)10s - %(funcName)10s - %(message)s')
    formatted_file = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)10s - %(funcName)10s - %(message)s')
    if not t_name:
        fh = logging.FileHandler(filename=logfile)
        fh.setFormatter(formatted_file)
        fh.addFilter(ContextFilter(self.jobdata.jobid))
        logger.addHandler(fh)
        ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        ch.setFormatter(formated)
        ch.addFilter(ContextFilter(self.jobdata.jobid))
        logger.addHandler(ch)
        return logger
    else:
        fh = logging.FileHandler(filename=logfile)
        fh.setFormatter(formatted_file)
        fh.addFilter(ContextFilter(self.jobdata.jobid))
        self.log.addHandler(fh)
        return fh
```